# Is __setitem__ method and square bracket assignment not the same?

Tags: python, oop, indexing, magic-methods

I assumed that square bracket assignment is a syntactic sugar for `__setitem__` magic-method. But as you can see from the result of this snippet it is not.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.value = value


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attribute = getattr(self.a, name)
        setattr(self, name, attribute)
        return getattr(self, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.__setitem__((1, 2), 4)
    b[1, 2] = 4

TypeError: 'B' object does not support item assignment
```

Could someone explain why square bracket assignment is not the same as `__setitem__` method calling?

Comment: This is because you're using new style classes and lookup for magic method in these seem to work diferent. If you skip the `(object)` inheritance it will work.

Comment: @skyking that's not great advice; old-style classes are deprecated, the OP should focus on implementing the logic they need in new-style classes.

Comment: @jonrsharp It's not an advice, it's just an observation. I agree that you should not use old-style classes (or maybe even python2) if you don't have good reasons to do it.